# how to make pdf.js canvas responsive

Tags: pdf.js

I am trying to use PDF.js in an Ionic2 app.

My code so far

```
PDFJS.getDocument(this.url).then( (doc) => {
  console.log(doc.numPages)
  doc.getPage(2).then((pdfPage) => {
    var SCALE = .1; 
    var pdfPageView = new PDFJS.PDFPageView({
      container: document.getElementById("container"),
      id: 2,
      defaultViewport: pdfPage.getViewport(SCALE),
      // We can enable text/annotations layers, if needed
      textLayerFactory: new PDFJS.DefaultTextLayerFactory(),
      annotationLayerFactory: new PDFJS.DefaultAnnotationLayerFactory()
    });

    pdfPageView.setPdfPage(pdfPage);
    pdfPageView.draw(); 

  })

});
```

My problem is that the div/canvas is not responsive.

Please suggest how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: you need to change canvas size/css and repaint page when you zoom-in/out (when devicePixelRatio changes)